# make a threshold frequency based on percentage of frequencies less than that?

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform, frequency, thresholding

Using MATLAB signal processing toolbox, I have created signals like dirichlet, chirp and etc and and obtained their fourier and cosine fourier transform. Now I want to find the frequency where for example A% frequencies are less than that and use it as a thresholding frequency to compact the signal and eliminate unnecessary details?
Could you please tell me a little more about thresholding frequencies and how to choose them in signal processing?

Comment: @John, please post your comment as an answer. I doubt this question will get any proper attention otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A Matlab code and illustration is given below, with the  discrete cosine transform (DCT):

```
nSample = 512;
pDataThreshold = 90/100 ; % percentage, as a float in [0 1]

time = linspace(0,1,nSample)';
data = sin(2*pi*4*sqrt(time));
dataTrans = dct(data);
dataThreshold = quantile(abs(dataTrans),pDataThreshold);
dataTransThreshold = dataTrans;
dataTransThreshold(abs(dataTrans) < dataThreshold) = 0;
dataCompact = idct(dataTransThreshold);

plot(time,[data,dataCompact]);
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Amplitude')
legend('Data',['DataCompact (',num2str(100*pDataThreshold),'%)'])
grid on
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to sort all N bins by increasing magnitude, select the magnitude at position A*N/100 in the sorted array, and then discard any frequencies with magnitude less than that in the original array.